# Definition for rule 'jsdoc/newline-after-description' was not found jsdoc/newline-after-description

Tags: javascript, wordpress, eslint, eslint-plugin-jsdoc

I got this error while linting the JS file I am using following configuration. I am doing linting as per WordPress Standards. and thus I have use some WordPress plugins.

```
{
  "extends": [
    "plugin:@wordpress/eslint-plugin/recommended"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "jsdoc"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true,
      "arrowFunctions": true,
      "blockBindings": true,
      "classes": true,
      "defaultParams": true,
      "modules": true
    },
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "globals": {
    "wp": false,
    "hm": false,
    "_": false
  },
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "commonjs": true,
    "jquery": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "camelcase": [1],
    "space-in-parens": [1, "always"],
    "no-trailing-spaces": [1],
    "spaced-comment": [0],
    "padded-blocks": [0],
    "prefer-template": [0],
    "max-len": [0],
    "no-else-return": [0],
    "func-names": [0],
    "object-shorthand": [0],
    "indent": ["error", "tab"],
    "space-before-function-paren": 0,
    "no-tabs": 0,
    "prefer-destructuring": 0,
    "no-param-reassign": 0,
    "curly": "error",
    "no-empty-function": "error",
    "no-global-assign": "error",
    "yoda": [ "error", "always" ],
    "no-undefined":"error",
    "comma-spacing": ["error", { "before": false, "after": true }],
    "lines-between-class-members": ["error", "always"],
    "arrow-spacing": "error",
    "jsdoc/check-alignment": 1,
    "jsdoc/check-param-names": 1,
    "jsdoc/check-tag-names": 1,
    "jsdoc/check-types": 0,
    "jsdoc/implements-on-classes": 1,
    "jsdoc/newline-after-description": 1,
    "jsdoc/no-undefined-types": 0,
    "jsdoc/require-jsdoc": 1,
    "jsdoc/require-param": 1,
    "jsdoc/require-param-description": 1,
    "jsdoc/require-param-name": 1,
    "jsdoc/require-param-type": 1,
    "jsdoc/require-returns": 1,
    "jsdoc/require-returns-check": 1,
    "jsdoc/require-returns-description": 1,
    "jsdoc/require-returns-type": 1,
    "jsdoc/valid-types": 1,
    "no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs": "off",
    "require-jsdoc": ["error", {
      "require": {
        "FunctionDeclaration": true,
        "MethodDefinition": true,
        "ClassDeclaration": true,
        "ArrowFunctionExpression": true,
        "FunctionExpression": true
      }
    }]
  },
  "settings": {
    "jsdoc": {
      "tagNamePreference" : {
        "param": "param",
        "returns": "return"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I got this configuration from the WordPress tutorials and stuck at the given error.

Error: Definition for rule 'jsdoc/newline-after-description' was not found  jsdoc/newline-after-description

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looks like that rule was removed/is out of date.

[Here's an issue to that effect on the eslint jsdoc plugin github site](https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-jsdoc/issues/1031):

> The rule was removed. Are you relying on a config which uses it?

I would remove that rule, though turning it off might also work.

> To pass linting I had to turn off the rule off in eslintrc.json: `"jsdoc/newline-after-description": "off",`

So swap

`"jsdoc/newline-after-description": 1,`

with

`"jsdoc/newline-after-description": "off",`

or

`"jsdoc/newline-after-description": 0,`

---

Btw, that looks like an eslint issue (more specifically an *eslint plugin for jsdoc* issue), not a *jslint* one. JSLint is different tool entirely: http://jslint.com I've edited your question's tags appropriately.

Comment: Note if you are using multi-library projects this value does not seem to be inherited and I had to add it to all my sub-projects. Linting then passed.